# Pass parameter in bbUI to another page failed

Tags: javascript, blackberry, blackberry-webworks

Based On : [Blackberry Wiki Screen](https://github.com/blackberry/bbUI.js/wiki/Screens)
With my full code : [My Full Code](http://pastebin.com/G8NL7u51)

If i user onscreenready function to PASS MY PARAMETER from page A like this :

```
ondomready: function(element, id) {
    if (id == 'UPDATE') {
            UPDATE_initialLoad(element, params);
    }
}
```

For pages that I would give / throw parameters (Let's just say page B), how do I win or get results / parameters provided by the previous form. I want to make a form update the data in the form, and will be filled all the time throwing fieldnya parameter data.

Im using like this in my Page B :

```
function UPDATE_initialLoad(element, params) { 
    setTimeout(UPDATE_loadAfterTimeout,100);
}

function UPDATE_loadAfterTimeout() {
    var id                  = data_id
    var nmDepan             = data_depan
    var nmBelakang          = data_belakang
    var phone               = data_phone
    var email               = data_email

    document.getElementById('txtID').value = id
    document.getElementById('txtNMDEPAN').value = nmDepan
    document.getElementById('txtNMBELAKANG').value = nmBelakang
    document.getElementById('txtPhone').value = phone
    document.getElementById('txtEmail').value = email      
}
```

But result is failed...

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to push data to the page:

```
bb.pushScreen("myPage.html", "UPDATE", myParams);
```

Then this will fire when the page is loaded:

```
ondomready: function(element, id, params) {
    if (id == 'UPDATE') {
        UPDATE_initialLoad(element, params);
    }
}
```

Make sure to pass the parameters to your delayed function:

```
function UPDATE_initialLoad(element, params) { 
    setTimeout(UPDATE_loadAfterTimeout(params),100);
}

function UPDATE_loadAfterTimeout(params) {
    var id                  = params['data_id'];
    var nmDepan             = params['data_depan'];
    var nmBelakang          = params['data_belakang'];
    var phone               = params['data_phone'];
    var email               = params['data_email'];

    document.getElementById('txtID').value = id
    document.getElementById('txtNMDEPAN').value = nmDepan
    document.getElementById('txtNMBELAKANG').value = nmBelakang
    document.getElementById('txtPhone').value = phone
    document.getElementById('txtEmail').value = email      
}
```

I hope this helps.